# Can't start Apache xampp

Tags: xampp

This is my error.log.

Tried a few things but nothing worked out.

```
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:37.294839 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5712:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:38.294842 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5712:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:39.883734 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5712:tid 384] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3 configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:39.883734 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5712:tid 384] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:39.883734 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5712:tid 384] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache' 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:39.899330 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5712:tid 384] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5276 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:43.104903 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5276:tid 344] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:43.761149 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5276:tid 344] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Fri Dec 05 12:37:44.089684 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5276:tid 344] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started it again with port 8080 and then switch back to port 80 and now the apache is starting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by correcting the directory in httpd.conf
MY team changed to the standard directory of xampp, which wasn't refered in httpd.conf